# Load section from Template docx file in PHPword

Tags: php, codeigniter, docx, phpword

I am planning to use `PHPWord` to generate a final report using PHP. Here is the approach, I plan to use :

- Prepare a master template file(*.docx) with multiple sections
- I will use few(or all) section within this master template, update it and put in the final report.
- Finally save the report file

My question is if it is possible to extract a particular section from the template file in PHPWord.

Any idea if this can be done ?